# how to filter the shape by text and delete selected shapes (In the example, I'm trying to filter shapes with text "No" and delete)

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

```vb
Sub delete_shapes()    
    Dim i As Integer

    ActiveSheet.Shapes.SelectAll

    For i = 1 To 4 Step 1
    If i < 5 Then

    For Each shape In ActiveSheet.Shapes
     'it has to match with shapes of text "NO"

      If Selection.ShapeRange(i).TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters.Text = "No" Then
   

     shape.Select
        Selection.Delete

     Else
     Debug.Print Selection.ShapeRange(i).TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters.Text
  ' running through the range of index
    i = i + 1
      End If

    Next shape

    End If

    Next i
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Please don't post questions which are just a title and some code, without any description of what *specific problem* you're having with that code.  FYI it's good practice *not* to increment the loop counter inside a `For...Next` loop: if you *need* to do that then you probably need a different type of loop.

Answer (score 1):

When deleting items from a collection it's often a good idea to go "backwards" so that deleted items don't affect the indexes of later items.

```vb
Sub delete_shapes()
    Dim i As Long, ws As Worksheet, txt, shp As Shape
    
    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For i = ws.Shapes.Count To 1 Step -1
        Set shp = ws.Shapes(i)
        txt = shp.TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters.Text
        Debug.Print shp.Name, txt
        If txt = "No" Then shp.Delete
    Next i
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Hello Tim
Thanks for the response and suggestion was well received.
however, with code the posted it prints the shape name and  text but not the particular shape has been selected and deleted.

Comment: O/P

Rectangle 98  YES 
Rectangle 97  YES 
Rectangle 96  YES 
Rectangle 9215              No  
Rectangle 92  4
Rectangle 91  3
Rectangle 90  2
Rectangle 19  1

Comment: When I ran it I noticed there was sometimes a lag where a shape had been deleted but still appeared to be there.  Switching to another sheet and back fixed that.  Is that what you're seeing?

Comment: I think maybe it's a matter of whitespace and casing?  `If Trim(LCase(txt)) = "no" then shp.Delete`.  Maybe have to deal with line breaks also

Comment: Thank you Tim & Daniel for your inputs!
It's been a great help!